# How to use Notepad++ for re-formatting indentations?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I've got a plugin that lets me paste in an unformatted XML and set up its tagged structure. However, I'd need to have one for e.g. C#. Haven't found such, though.

1. Where can I find retagging plugin for Notepad++ (for C# code)?
2. How can I go about writing my own if there's no such thing?

Note: This is **not** a question on how to enable NP++ to indent text I type but reformatting a pasted in chunk of text written already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only plugin I know of to do this is [nppastyle](http://code.google.com/p/nppastyle/), that will allow you to integrate [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net) with Notepad++.

However, if using Notepad++ is not a must, there are [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253/is-there-any-tool-for-reformatting-c-sharp-code) options [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101/is-there-an-automatic-code-formatter-for-c).

Comment: +1 for suggestions beyond the scope of the the question. NPP is not a must. However, in most cases, it's the best choice. Not always, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Install plugin for Notepad++ : [here](https://csscriptnpp.codeplex.com/)
2. Open some CS file. Write script, edit, copy, paste and so on.
3. Select all source code (Ctrl + A).
4. From menu select : Plugins -> CS-Scripts -> Format Document (shortkey Ctrl + F8).

   And CS script is formatted. That's all.